# Difference between `int *p` and `int (*p)[3]`?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, initialization, implicit-conversion

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int *p = arr;
    int (*r)[3] = arr;
    
    printf("%u %u", p, r);
    printf("\n%d %d %d", p[0], p[1], p[2]);
    
    printf("\n%d %d %d", r[0], r[1], r[2]);
    printf("\n%d %d %d", *r[0], *r[1], *r[2]);
    printf("\n%d %d %d", (*r)[0], (*r)[1], (*r)[2]);
}
```

Output:

```
1483745184 1483745184
1 2 3
1483745184 1483745196 1483745208
1 0 -647513344
1 2 3
```

As you can see `p` and `r` contains same address, then

- why does `p[0]` work but `r[0]` doesn't?
- what goes behind `p[0]`?
- why does `(*r)[0]` work but others don't?

EDIT: Other than accepted answer, this answer is also helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/71218214/12491154

Comment: Compare `sizeof (*r)` with `sizeof (*p)`. You should also print the addresses you are generating and compare how far they are apart. While one points to a single `int` the other points to an array `int[3]`. Accordingly the indexing the elements is done in steps of 1 or 3 `int` variables. You should also check what type `*p` and `*r` have and if you can print it the way you do.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. You're looking at nonsense.

Comment: Side note: You are not allowed to print pointers using `%u`. Use `%p` instead and cast the pointers to `void*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between these two declarations

```
int *p = arr;
int (*r)[3] = arr;
```

is that in the second declaration there is used a wrong initializer. The array `arr` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int *`.  So in the second declaration the initialized object and the initializer have different pointer types and there is no implicit conversion between the types.

To make the second declaration correct you need to write

```
int (*r)[3] = &arr;
```

Now the both pointers p and r stores the same value: the address of the extent of memory occupied by the array but have different types.

For example if you will write

```
printf( "sizeof( *p ) = %zu\n", sizeof( *p ) );
printf( "sizeof( *r ) = %zu\n", sizeof( *r ) );
```

then the first call will output the size of an object of the type `int` that is equal to `4` while the second call will output the size of the whole array of the type `int[3]` that is equal to `12`.

In this your call of printf

```
printf("%u %u", p, r);
```

there are used incorrect conversion specifiers with pointers. Instead you have to write

```
printf("%p %p", ( void * )p, ( void * )r);
```

The expressions r[0], r[1], r[2] have the type int[3]. Used in this call

```
printf("\n%d %d %d", r[0], r[1], r[2]);
```

they as it was mentioned are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements. But these arrays except the array r[0] that denotes the array arr do not exist. So there takes place an access to memory beyond the array arr,

You could write

```
printf( "\n%p\n", ( void * )r[0] );
```

and this call will be equivalent to

```
printf("\n%p\n", ( void * )arr );
```

This call of printf

```
printf("\n%d %d %d", *r[0], *r[1], *r[2]);
```

is also incorrect because arrays `r[1]` and `r[2]` of the type `int[3]` do not exist.

This call of printf

```
printf("\n%d %d %d", (*r)[0], (*r)[1], (*r)[2]);
```

outputs elements of the array `arr` due to using the expression `*r`.

Comment: So here I understand, due to the type `int*`, when I do `p[1]` it means `*(p + 4)`, and when I do `r[1]` it means `*(r + 12)` because of `int[3]` type which has overall size of 12 bytes, am I right?

Comment: @jastor_007 It would be more correctly to write that p[1] means *( int * )( ( char * )p + sizeof( int ) ) and r[1] means *( int( * )[3] )( ( char * )r + sizeof( int[3] ) )

Comment: That's very tricky to understand, but yeah that's what I meant. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `r` and `p` is solely in the type.

The first thing to note is that the assignment `int (*r)[3] = arr;` is not correct; `arr` in assignments decays to a pointer to its first element, an `int`, which is a different type than `r` which is a pointer to an array of three ints. Now admittedly, C originally wasn't that picky, and assignments between different pointer types and between pointers and integers weren't given much thought — it's all numbers, right? But modern C tries to be more type safe, for good reason, so the proper assignment would be `int (*r)[3] = &arr;`: If you want the address of an array, just take the address. Your code "works" because *numerically* the address of the first element *is* the address of the array. It's the type that's wrong, not the value.

Now to your confusion: As you noted, both point to the same address; but the object `p` is pointing to is a simple int (which just so happens to be followed by two more ints in memory, together comprising `arr`), while `r` is pointing to the array itself.

Consequently, the type of `*p` is `int` while the type of `*r` is `int[3]`, and consequently to that `sizeof *r == 3 * sizeof *p` holds.

As you know, C blurs that distinction in most contexts: For example, you could legitimately say `p = *r;`, because arrays are "adjusted" or "decay" to pointers to their first element in assignments or parameter initialization.

But for `sizeof` they don't. That is because indexing adds `index * sizeof(element)` to the numerical value of the pointer; if the pointer points to an entire array, like `r` (as opposed to its first element only, like `p`), the second element will be *the next array*, which isn't there — there is only one array, so your program is faulty.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int arr[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
    int (*r)[3] = arr;

    printf("%p %p\n", (void*)r[0], (void*)r[1]);
}
```

This little program illustrates this. Note how `arr` again decays to the address of its first element; only this time, the first element of that two-dimensional array is an array itself, of three ints, so it fits perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The types of `p` and `r` are very different:

- `p` is a pointer to `int`, initialized to point to the first element of array `arr`,
- `r` is a pointer to an array of 3 `int`: the initialization is incorrect, it should be `r = &arr`.
- `printf("%u %u", p, r)` has undefined behavior: `%u` expects an argument with type `unsigned int`, `p` and `r` are pointers which should be cast as `(void *)` and convered with `%p`.
- `printf("\n%d %d %d", p[0], p[1], p[2])` is correct and produces `1 2 3` as expected
- `printf("\n%d %d %d", r[0], r[1], r[2])` has undefined behavior for multiple reasons: `r[0]` and `r[1]` decay as pointers to `int`, they should be cast as `(void *)` and printed using `%p`. `r[2]` is an invalid pointer: computing its value and passing it as an argument has undefined behavior.
- postfix unary operators bind stronger than prefix operators, so `*r[0]` as parsed as `*(r[0])`, which is the same as `r[0][0]`, the first element of the array `arr`. Conversely `*r[1]` is equivalent to `r[1][0]`, which refers to an invalid area, beyond the end of `arr`, same for `*r[2]`, so reading both of these cause undefined behavior.
- conversely `(*r)[0]` is the same as `(r[0])[0]`, hence `r[0][0]`, the first element of `arr`, and similary `(*r)[1]` is the same as `r[0][1]` so `printf("\n%d %d %d", (*r)[0], (*r)[1], (*r)[2])` outputs `1 2 3` just like `printf("\n%d %d %d", p[0], p[1], p[2])`.

`p` and `r` (initialized as `r = &arr`) indeed point to the same location, but they have different types which must be taken into consideration when writing code.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int *p = arr;
    int (*r)[3] = &arr;

    printf("arr: address %p,  sizeof(arr): %2zu bytes,  sizeof(*arr): %2zu bytes\n",
           (void *)arr, sizeof(arr), sizeof(*arr));
    printf("p:   address %p,  sizeof(p):   %2zu bytes,  sizeof(*p):   %2zu bytes\n",
           (void *)p, sizeof(p), sizeof(*p));
    printf("r:   address %p,  sizeof(r):   %2zu bytes,  sizeof(*r):   %2zu bytes\n",
           (void *)r, sizeof(r), sizeof(*r));

    printf("arr: %p,  arr+1: %p\n", (void *)arr, (void *)(arr + 1));
    printf("p:   %p,  p+1:   %p\n", (void *)p, (void *)(p + 1));
    printf("r:   %p,  r+1:   %p\n", (void *)r, (void *)(r + 1));

    printf("%d %d %d\n", p[0], p[1], p[2]);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", r[0][0], r[0][1], r[0][2]);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", (*r)[0], (*r)[1], (*r)[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
arr: address 0x7fff544137f8,  sizeof(arr): 12 bytes,  sizeof(*arr):  4 bytes
p:   address 0x7fff544137f8,  sizeof(p):    8 bytes,  sizeof(*p):    4 bytes
r:   address 0x7fff544137f8,  sizeof(r):    8 bytes,  sizeof(*r):   12 bytes
arr: 0x7fff544137f8,  arr+1: 0x7fff544137fc
p:   0x7fff544137f8,  p+1:   0x7fff544137fc
r:   0x7fff544137f8,  r+1:   0x7fff54413804
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`*p` is a pointer to an array, while `(*r)[3]` is an array pointer to an array.

`*p` will point to the values/indices of the array arr whereas `(*r)[i]` will point to the memory location/address of the indices.

`*r` will point nowhere as `(*r)` and `*r` are DIFFERENT.